# How to get multiple keys in couchdb sorting by date

Tags: couchdb

I have a view which emits values as

```
function(doc) {
 var d = new Date(doc.created_date);
 emit([d,doc.unique_id],doc);
}
```

Here i have to get multiple unique_id's in one query. so i use Keys=["unique_id1","unique_id1"] to get the id's.. but i need them to be sorted by date and also get the unique_id's. If i query as mentioned above i am not getting any results from db.but if i change the view as below and query it i am getting results correctly but not sorted by date.

```
function(doc) {
 emit(doc.unique_id,doc);
}
```

Could anybody suggest me how to get both in a single query????

```
Select * from db where unique_id in {"1","3"} order by date
```

This is what i need in couchdb

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. In CouchDB, you can either query by a unique key or set of keys, or you can query for a range. So, if you want to query by a set of unique ID's without having to specify their creation date in the query, you cannot have the creation date in the key, and so CouchDB can't order by creation date for you. In that case, you could use a unique-ID-only key and sort the results by created_date on the client side (i.e. after querying).

The alternative is that you specify a key including [unique_id, created_date], but in that case you can't query for [1, *] and [3, *] without also including [2, *] (which you could again filter out after querying, on the client side).

Comment: Ya thanks for your help. Actually i need the docs to be sorted according to the Created_date only.. but i need also unique id's with it. So i need how to pass the keys for getting this work..???

Comment: You should probably use a unique_id-only key (i.e. your second view function), then sort the results in your client code.

Comment: That's the prob i have.... i need the docs to be sorted in server side itself since i am using pagination. so that i cannot take docs to client and sort it since it will give me unordered results..

Comment: Well, then your data is probably structured wrongly for CouchDB. Why are you querying for multiple unique ID's at the same time?

Comment: I need them all at once because i cannot call a view every time for getting different id's corresponding to a single user.

Comment: Try adding some more context to your question, then I (and others) can perhaps solve your problem somehow. I.e. what kind of documents are involved, how are they related, what are you trying to achieve with the query.